# Linux commands for Apache-ds LDAP

Tags: apacheds

What is the **Linux commands for Apache-ds LDAP** server to do the following operation

- Schema import (LDIF file import)
- LDAP search on objectClass
- LDAP add/modify/delete operations

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Linux commands, belongs to http://unix.stackexchange.com


Answer (score 1):

Under CentOS I'm using `openldap-clients` to execute commands against ApacheDS:

```
yum install openldap-clients
```

I used the following commands successfully:

*Import schema*

```
ldapadd -h localhost -p 10389 -D "uid=admin,ou=system" -f rfc2985.ldif -x -W
```

*Change password*

```
ldappasswd -h localhost -p 10389 -D "uid=admin,ou=system" -x -A -S -W
```

*Filter by object class*

```
ldapsearch -h localhost -p 10389 -D "uid=admin,ou=system" -W "(objectclass=organization)"
```

There are also the following commands that I haven't used before, check the man page for more details:

- `ldapadd`
- `ldapmodify`
- `ldapdelete`